# Получить массив строк из textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть обычная textarea с фиксированной шириной, в ней введен сплошной текст без переноса строк, textarea сама добавила переносы где текст не вмещается в заданную ширину. Мне нужно получить массив этих самых строк так как их видит юзер. Т.е обычное value.split("\n") не работает

Comment: Что Вы уже пытались предпринять для достижения необходимого результата? Дополните вопрос вашими наработками.

Comment: А в каких единицах задаётся ширина textarea? Вы знаете, сколько помещается символов в строке до переноса?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty: извечный вопрос - шрифт `monospace` ? )))))

Comment: У меня шире вопрос. Как, имея на руках коллекцию, полученную методом getClientRects(), т.е. по 1 прямоугольнику на каждую строку текста в inline-элементе, "вынуть" текст из каждого отдельного прямоугольника? Никакого нет трюка для этого, только количество строк посчитать можно?

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov: по сути, это то же самое. Только здесь textarea и есть один большой Rect.

Comment: @UMode по сути, у вас есть чем помочь автору вопроса?

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov: я, в данный момент, как раз занимаюсь этим вопросом. У Вас претензии ко мне?

Comment: @UMode чувствую себя беспомощно на месте автора и не понимаю, какие тут можно сделать наработки кроме операций с массивом слов — абсурдно сложных на фоне лаконичности самого вопроса. Извините, вырвалось.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov: согласен, задача нетривиальная. Ещё если кроссбраузерность... %( Но, интересно же. Завтра ещё поковыряю, а то 4:43 на часах... Zzz

Answer (score 2):

Периодически видел на разных площадках подобный вопрос, но приемлемых ответов так и не нашёл. Попытался реализовать самостоятельно:

```js
function fVisibleRowsToArray(textarea) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="fakediv" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity:0;"></div>');
  let fakespan = fakediv.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
  fakespan.textContent = textarea.value + '\n STOP';
  let TaS = getComputedStyle(textarea);
  let aStyleProps = 'display width padding border font lineHeight boxSizing whiteSpace overflowWrap overflow letterSpacing wordSpacing'.split(' ');
  aStyleProps.forEach((el) => { fakespan.style[el] = TaS[el]; });
  let aTextRows = [];
  let range = new Range(), sel, rect, height;
  for (let end = 0, start = 0, nLen = fakespan.textContent.length; end < nLen; ++end) {
    range.setStart(fakespan.firstChild, start);
    range.setEnd(fakespan.firstChild, end);
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.empty(); sel.addRange(range);
    rect = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    if (height && rect.height > height) {
      start = --end;
      aTextRows.push(sel.toString().slice(0, -1));
    } else {
      height = rect.height;
    }
  }
  fakediv.remove();
  console.log(aTextRows); // Only for demo
  return aTextRows;
}

/* Only for demo */
fontsize.addEventListener('input', function() {
  source.style.fontSize = this.value + 'px'; fVisibleRowsToArray(source);
});
source.addEventListener('input', () => fVisibleRowsToArray(source));
new ResizeObserver(() => fVisibleRowsToArray(source)).observe(source);
```

```css
#source { width: 300px; font: 16px serif; }
```

```html
<p>Размер шрифта :<input id="fontsize" type="range" min="8" max="96" value="16"></p>
<textarea id="source" name="" cols="30" rows="10">START 454545454545455iiiiiiiiihlhhny88ngfj7tgjt7 tyf7tgt7tgfjkgktt kukgtt666ktg kgkggk7giuguigigikgk k44gkgkgkylyly 455455iiihny88ngfj7tgjt7tyf7tgt7tgfjkgkttkukgtt6gkgk7giuguigigikgkk44gklylyl
MIDDLE
45iiihlhhny88ngfj7tgjt7 tyf7tgt7tgf jkgkttkukgtt66ktgkgk gkgkgk 7giuguigigik gkkkgkg kgkgkylly 545 45455ii iihl hhny88ngfj7tgjt7 tyf7tgt7tgfjkgkttk ukgtt66ktg kgkgk gkgk7giu guigigikgk kgkylylyly END</textarea>
```

*Отлично работает в Chrome и Edge. В Firefox через раз (на перспективу;-).*

Comment: А снипет должен запускаться? У меня в хроме ничего не показывает...

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov: только что проверил здесь - всё работает. Тоже Хром.

Comment: Это у меня что-то паранормальное, снипет кода не хотел запускаться в масштабе страницы отличном от 100%.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov: да, есть такая проблема. Тоже изменил масштаб и попытался запустить - белый экран. Но, я не пользуюсь масштабированием, поэтому не сталкиваюсь с подобными багами. Кстати, 200% работает норм.